# Is there limit of history size in Codemirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

In my app I have multiple files and I use a separate Codemirror.doc for each file to store file history. I don't want end up storing a very huge file containing all history. Is there some limit for history size in codemirror? And if so, can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option `undoDepth` in Codemirror configuration which defaults to 200. You can easily change it, when you initialize an editor.